# How can I securely generate the same private key in JS and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptography

I need to create an internet-less password reset feature. My hardware uses a web (JS/HTML) interface and a PHP back-end. I've seen this in the wild before: the user gets a short key which they read to the IT person, and the IT person generates a short private response key. The user then uses this key and is able to get to a password change screen.

Yes, I have a "security questions" feature already. This is going to be for last-ditch recovery, like if your last Admin user dies or something. Also, it cannot be time-sensitive like standard keyfob RSA. Some of these units are literally on top of mountains, so a person might have a considerable lag time between generating the public key, receiving the private one, and setting it on their device.

I've considered just taking something like the unit's serial and the date and running them through some sort of encryption, but I wonder if you guys have some simpler way? Hell, I could encrypt it the same way I do the passwords, but the strings that generates can be... unwieldy. Ideally this would be maybe a 10-12 character string.

Comment: Of course the second I post this I realize openssl_encrypt() is a thing. I'll try that in the morning and update if it does what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty slick way to do it. I took a set of data ($serial, hard-coded $seed, $date, and $type for account type) md5'd it, and encrypted that with openssl using an encrypt function I found on another answer, then did sort of the first half of a checksum to condense the long string to something 1/3 the length. You just run genkey($serial,$seed,$date,$type) to get a nice short string, such as "URMYVAFYNE". The person on the other end does the same thing, then compares the strings to see if they match. Then they generate a second string using the first one as the $seed, and the client enters that to have it verified... you get the idea.

```
        function genkey($serial,$seed,$date,$type) {
            $fullstring = $serial.$seed.$date.$type;
            $md5 = md5($fullstring);
            $encrypted = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt',$md5);
            return condense(condense($encrypted));
        }

        function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) 
        {
            $output = false;
            $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
            $secret_key = '[REDACTED]'; //32 byte
            $secret_iv = '[REDACTED]'; //16 byte
            // hash
            $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);    
            // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes 
            $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
            if ( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
                $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
                $output = base64_encode($output);
            } else if( $action == 'decrypt' ) {
                $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
            }
            return $output;
        }

        function condense($str) {
            $arr = str_split($str, 3);
            $retstr = '';
            for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
                $sum=WordSum($arr[$i]);
                $letternum = $sum%26 + 65; //ascii code for capital letter
                $letter = chr($letternum);
                $retstr .= $letter;
            }
            return $retstr;
        }
```

Comment: Just remember if you use this to replace [REDACTED] with your own strings.

Comment: Oh and it goes without saying but I wound up having JS call the function via Ajax.